# How to make one particular pipeline be triggered for change corresponding to that pipeline applications?

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Our team is developing a project which contains some 7 API's and 3 Function apps. They all are placed in a single Azure repo with only one '.sln' file for all the API's and Function apps. I am asked to build different pipelines for all the API's and Function apps.

Our expected work of pipelines is, if there is a change in one of the API's or Function apps, then pipeline corresponding to that API/Fn app has to be triggered but not the remaining pipelines. But if there is a change in any of the API's/Fn apps then all of the pipelines are getting triggered.

So I have added the path filter in the build pipelines. But from then onwards auto triggering of pipeline for changes in API's/Fn apps is not working. What should be solution for this approach.

### My pipeline

trigger:
branches:
include:

- My branch name
  paths:
  include:
- '**/x api/*'

exclude:

- '**/z api/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to specify a [tag trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags) in a pipeline. And this pipeline trigger other all pipelines via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). When you want to trigger this pipeline, create a tag. For example:

```
# specific tag
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - v2.1
```